# Weird metric value in graphite from collectd

Tags: python, graphite, collectd, grafana

I wrote custom python plugin for collectd:

```
import collectd
import random

def read_callback():
    value = random.randint(0, 1500)
    val = collectd.Values()
    val.plugin = 'test'
    val.plugin_instance = 'random'
    val.type = 'counter'
    val.type_instance = 'random'
    val.values = [value]
    val.dispatch()

collectd.register_read(read_callback)
```

So I expected to see values from 0 to 1500 in graphite, but got the following list of floats with value much more than 1500:

[image]

I don`t have any problems with basic plugins and their metrics, but here very strange behavior. 
Does any one know why and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in collectd-graphite flag `StoreRates` it was set to True, that is why collectd send diff value from the previous and if the new value was less the previous I got weird behaviour.

How to fix same problem: set StoreRates to false.